# Analysis of Logarithmic-Polynomial series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, logarithms

> I am asked the following problem: Given $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+$,
>   determine the values of $a$ and $b$ for which the series
>   $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^a\ln{(n)}^b}$$ converges.

To begin, I used the Cauchy condensation to transform the series into $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{n(1-a)}}{n^b}$. My intuition from here was to use the ratio test, and from that I need to look at $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\{\frac{2^{1-a}n^b}{(n+1)^b}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left\{2^{1-a}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty \cdot \lim_{n\to \infty} \left\{\frac{n^b}{(n+1)^b}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$$

My problem arises in computing the last limit, $\left\{\frac{n^b}{(n+1)^b}\right\}$. Intuitively, I see it as tending towards 1. However, I can't find a way to prove this for every positive $b$ (in particular, irrational $b$) using what we've covered in class thus far. I'm not allowed to use L'hopital's rule, or anything involving derivatives or integrals thus far, and we've only gone over some very basic facts about continuity. Is there a way to compute this limit using only elementary means? Is it the case that that my intuition is wrong?

Comment: Also see http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/bertrand/bertrand.html